# How to change permissions for Gemfile created with Docker for Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, permissions, docker-for-windows

I'm working with a dockerized rails application, however whenever I make a change to the `Gemfile` the file permissions change to an unkown user, and I'm unable to do anything to the file whether I'm inside the container or not.

How can I make it so that I'm able to manipulate the file again?

Here's my `.docker-copmose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  postgres:

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - ${APP:-5432}:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db/dumps:/db/dumps # Mount the directory DB dumps folder
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 3x4mpl3

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
    entrypoint: /app/bin/entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - ${APP_WEB_PORT:-3000}:3000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:3x4mpl3@postgres:5432/app_development
      RAILS_ENV: development
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the file ownership from outside of the docker and after that you can manipulate the file.